# How to correctly use pull to refresh in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel, pull-to-refresh

I'm trying to implement pull to refresh in my screen. But I have a problem, when updating I need to execute two requests in parallel, but as you can see from my code, I do not wait for the result from two requests, I update the state as data arrives:

```
fun refresh() {

 viewModelScope.launch(genericErrorHandler) {
            launch {             
             
                    val data = interactor.firstRequest()
                    _state.update {
                        it.copy(
                            firstData = data,
                          
                        )
                    }               
            }

            launc {                 
                _state.update {
                    it.copy(secondData = interactor.fetchSecondData())
                }
            }
        }
}
```

But I need to add  `isRefreshing` flag to my ViewModel to track when the refresh action has started and finished.

```
val pullRefreshState = rememberPullRefreshState(
        state.isRefreshing,
        onRefresh,
    )
```

And how to determine when to set the value for the isRefreshing  flag to false ? Please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

As my understanding, you don't want user to do accident pull request when the viewmodel is loading. So first you can create a

```kotlin
enum class ScreenState { 
    LOADING, READY 
}
```

and let the ViewModel keep the StateFlow<ScreenState>, with this your UI will acknowledge when it is ready for pull request.

Next, besides logic part, on the UI part you can stop user by passing `enabled` of

```kotlin
Modifier.pullRefresh(state: PullRefreshState, enabled: Boolean)
```